# Id not getting in input text field using dropdown javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using javascript for getting dropdown select id `id='odrid'`,
here is the script:

```
$('#odrid').change(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        'fetch.php',
        'odrid='+$('#odrid').val(),
        function(result){
            $('#item').empty();
            $.each(result, function(){
                $('#item').val(this['item']);
            });
        }
    );
});
```

This drop down script runs in another script for adding dynamic form field:

```
<script>
    $('#odrid').change(function(){
        $.getJSON(
            'fetch.php',
            'odrid='+$('#odrid').val(),
            function(result){
                $('#item').empty();
                $.each(result, function(){
                    $('#item').val(this['item']);
                });
            }
       );
   });

   $(function() {
       // register listener
       $('.form-control1').on("change.add", calculateSum);
       // initial calculation
       calculateSum();

    // button for adding new row
    $(".addmore").click(function() {
        $('.form-control1').off("change.add");
        //addRow();
        var count = $('#counter').val();

        $("<tr>" +
             "<td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>" +
             "<td><select id='odrid'><?php

        $query = mysql_query('select * from cart_sample');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['odrid'].'>'.$row['odrid']. '</option>';
        }

        ?></select></td>" +

        "<td ><input id='item' type='text'   name='txt_quantity[]' value=''   /></td>" +

        "</tr>").insertAfter("tr:last-child");

        count++;
        $('#counter').val(count);
        $('.form-control1').on("change.add", calculateSum);
        calculateSum();

    });
</script>
```

---

**this is my front end:**
[image]

1. The problem is that I didn't get the value of `#item` in my output.

   - How can I fix this issue? does anyone know the problem in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `result.result` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with your id

you are using $("#item") in your jquery and you have defined items as your id

```
<input id='items' type='text'   name='txt_quantity[]' value=''   />
```

change it to item

```
<input id='item' type='text'   name='txt_quantity[]' value=''   />
```

or change

```
$("#items") in jquery
```

and it should work as expected

Comment: sorry it was my mistake now i edited my code.and still its not working

Comment: okey can you please check your console is there any error(s) or not